# Apex Chart not rendered in Lightning Design System

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, lightning-design-system, visualforce-charting

I developed a really simple page where I have several apex bar charts, based on values calculated in an apex controller.

Now, when I put the charts into a `<div class="slds"></div>`, the bars do not render ! The charts appear, but the bar do not :

**Rendered in classic :**
[image: Rendered in classic]

**Not rendered in slds :**
[image: Not rendered in slds]

The code :

```
<div class="slds">    
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-col--padded">
            <apex:chart data="{!listCAEnCours}" height="400" width="700">
                <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="Valeur" title="Total HT" grid="true" minimum="0"/>
                <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="Libelle" title="Retard"/>
                <apex:barSeries title="Retard de créance" orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="Libelle" yField="Valeur">
                    <apex:chartTips height="20" width="100" valueField="Valeur" />
                </apex:barSeries>
            </apex:chart>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col--padded">
            <apex:chart data="{!listCAFacture}" height="400" width="700">
                <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="Valeur" title="Total HT" grid="true" minimum="0"/>
                <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="Libelle" title="Retard"/>
                <apex:barSeries title="Mois" orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="Libelle" yField="Valeur">
                    <apex:chartTips height="20" width="100" valueField="Valeur" />
                 </apex:barSeries>
             </apex:chart>
         </div>
     </div>                
</div>
```

As I said, really simple...

Did someone already faced that issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: You could check in developer tools whether some properties are being overriden by the slds classes.

Comment: Well thank you, because actually there was a css property in slds which was entering in conflict with the whole page.
So for those who are wondering, you have to add into your page .slds [hidden], .slds template { display: block; } ; that means you cannot use the property hidden on any html tag into your page.

Comment: @JulienGaïotto Please post that as the answer to your question for the benefit of others who might encounter the same issue at some point in time and want to search for a question with an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Glad you found out the issue. Post that as an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve that issue, you actually have to add some style to your VFPage / Lightning Component :

```
.slds [hidden], .slds template {
    display: block;
}
```

Don't forget to add .THIS before the classes if you are building a Lightning Component.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to add "-scope" to the css reference.

```
.slds-scope [hidden], .slds-scope template {
              display: block;
            }
```